# Firebase Phone Authentication not working after creating a signed APK

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

My app worked fined until I generated a signed APK in Android Studio when I do Authentication on signed Apk it just shows me a Toast "cannot verify phone and create account". It worked fine in debug mode.and when I made a debug APK it also ran fine in it, but not in Signed APK. I am unable  to figure out what is causing this error that Authentication is not working in just Signed APK

My code

```
   public class Register2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseAuth auth;
    DatabaseReference reference;

    String otpCode;
    String verificationId;
    MaterialEditText phone, optEnter;
    Button next;
    CountryCodePicker countryCodePicker;

    PhoneAuthCredential credential;
    Boolean verificationOnProgress = false;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    TextView resend;

    PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register2);

        phone = findViewById(R.id.phone);
        optEnter = findViewById(R.id.codeEnter);
        countryCodePicker = findViewById(R.id.ccp);
        next = findViewById(R.id.nextBtn);
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        resend = findViewById(R.id.resendOtpBtn);

        resend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // todo:: resend OTP
            }
        });

        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (!phone.getText().toString().isEmpty() && phone.getText().toString().length() == 10) {
                    if (!verificationOnProgress) {
                        next.setEnabled(false);
                        String phoneNum = "+" + countryCodePicker.getSelectedCountryCode() + phone.getText().toString();
                        Log.d("phone", "Phone No.: " + phoneNum);
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        requestPhoneAuth(phoneNum);
                    } else {
                        next.setEnabled(false);
                        optEnter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        otpCode = optEnter.getText().toString();
                        if (otpCode.isEmpty()) {
                            optEnter.setError("Required");
                            return;
                        }

                        credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, otpCode);
                        verifyAuth(credential);
                    }

                } else {
                    phone.setError("Valid Phone Required");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void requestPhoneAuth(String phoneNumber) {
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, 60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, this,
                new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCodeAutoRetrievalTimeOut(String s) {
                        super.onCodeAutoRetrievalTimeOut(s);
                        Toast.makeText(Register2.this, "OTP Timeout, Please Re-generate the OTP Again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        resend.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                        super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
                        verificationId = s;
                        token = forceResendingToken;
                        verificationOnProgress = true;
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        next.setText("Verify");
                        next.setEnabled(true);
                        optEnter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {


                        verifyAuth(phoneAuthCredential);


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(Register2.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
    }


    private void verifyAuth(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        auth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                    Toast.makeText(Register2.this, "Phone Verified", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
                    String userid = firebaseUser.getUid();
                    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UserIds").child(userid);
                    reference.setValue(true);


                    //checkUserProfile();


                } else {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Toast.makeText(Register2.this, "Can not Verify phone and Create Account.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            checkUserProfile();
        }
    }


    private void checkUserProfile() {


        Intent intent = new Intent(Register2.this, Details3.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After uploading the application to google play store, you have to update the SHA-1/SHA-255 fingerprint in firebase. You'll find the SHA-1/SHA-255 in play store as given.

1. Navigate to the **Google Play Console** and login
2. Choose the application you are signing
3. Go to **Release Management** > **App Signing**
4. Copy /Download the SHA-1 or SHA-256 certificate fingerprint from the App signing certificate section

[image: Screenshot]

Now, add the SHA-1/SHA-255 to the firebase and your app will be back again.

Comment: Is it okay that the copy of the released APK that is still in my pc is not authenticating?

Comment: @ShivamSingh After going through the given steps, download the app from the play store and check once if everything is okay. Well your firebase project may have more than one fingerprint so you can keep the release and debug fingerprint both together and both apps should work.

Comment: I tried changing only the SHA-1 but it was not working then I changed SHA-256 too. I got the OTP. But data from the Firestore is not showing in the app. Should I remove the old SHA-1 and SHA-256?

Comment: Yes, you can try that. Once you updated the keys, wait for a while to reflect. This is not mentioned anywhere in docs but it works sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add your app [SHA-1 Fingerprint in Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/general) if not please follow this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#assistant).

Comment: I added that's why I was able to verify real numbers in debug APK